# Stop audio array loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, break

I'm trying to build a drum sequencer and have started with a single array of audio which a counter that can loop continuously.
I want to stop the audio on a double click, which I've done with a stop function. However when looking at the console the counter is still incrementing. I've tried to stop that using break but am told it's an illegal statement.

Here's the code, thanks for any help.

```
const drumSequencer = [true, false, false, true, true, false, false, false];

const audio = document.getElementById('soundOne');


function start() {
    let counter = 0;
    setInterval(function(){ 
        if (drumSequencer[counter] === true) { 
        audio.play().catch(function(error) {
        console.log('error', error)
         })}
        console.log(counter);
        counter++;
        //loops through array
            if (counter === 8) {
                counter = 0;
            }
            //stops array if double click on screen
            if (document.addEventListener().dblclick) {
            break;
            }
    }, 1000);}



function stop() {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
}

//starts audio
document.addEventListener('click', start)

//stops audio
document.addEventListener('dblclick', stop)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const drumSequencer = [true, false, false, true, true, false, false, false];

const audio = document.getElementById('soundOne');
let stopped = false;
let counter = 0;

function restart(){
   counter = 0;
   stopped = false;
   start();
}

function start() {

    setTimeout(function(){ 
        if (drumSequencer[counter] === true) { 
        audio.play().catch(function(error) {
        console.log('error', error)
         })}
        console.log(counter);
        counter++;
        //loops through array
            if (counter === 8) {
                counter = 0;
            }
            //stops array if double click on screen
            if (stopped==false) {
              start();
            }
    }, 1000);}



function stop() {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    stopped = true;
}

//starts audio
document.addEventListener('click', restart)

//stops audio
document.addEventListener('dblclick', stop)
```

I have edited your code. please check it

Comment: Thanks, almost, I changed stopped from a const to let, and the audio stops on a double click. However the counter never increases past 0 so I get a beat every second, when it should only be on the 1st, 3rd and 5th second.

Comment: put the  let counter = 0; outside start() function.  And then again in restart() function set counter = 0;

Comment: That worked, thanks! So if I'm understanding this, then on the single click restart() is called which calls the start() and plays the loop if the variable stopped is false. Then on the double click stopped becomes true and so the loop doesn't run. But I don't understand why use stopped and restart, and why the break statement didn't work.